# Intersection of the sets of generalized doubly stochastic matrices and of orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

The definition of a doubly stochastic matrix can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix). We say a square matrix $A$ is a **generalized doubly stochastic matrix** if the sums of each rows and columns of $A$ all equal $1$, but $A$ doesn't have to be non-negative.

An interesting fact (which is also easy to prove) about doubly stochastic matrices is: if $A$ is doubly stochastic and orthogonal, then $A$ is actually a permutation matrix.

What is the intersection set for a generalized doubly stochastic matrix set and orthogonal matrix set? More specifically, can any one give me an example of an $N \times N$ matrix $A$, which satisfy the following constraints:

- $AA^T=I$
- $A 1=1$
- $A^T 1=1$
- there exists at least one entry $A_{i,j}$, satisfying $A_{i,j}<0$

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just take any solution to $x+y+z=x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and form the matrix $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} x&y&z\\y&z&x\\z&x&y\end{array}\right).$$

For instance, take $x = -\frac13$ and $y = z = \frac23$.  More generally, choose the roots of the cubic $x^3 - x^2 + c$ for some small positive real $c$.

Comment: Thanks, Erick, This is a nice example.